# How to install tun on Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: ubuntu-16.04, tun-tap

I try to install tun on Ubuntu 16.04, it generates the tun.ko, but it still doesn't work.

1

> Uname -a Linux host-name 4.10.0-42-generic #46~16.04.1-Ubuntu SMP Mon
>   Dec 4 15:57:59 UTC 2017 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux

2

> apt-get install linux-source-4.10.0

3

> cd /usr/src/linux-source-4.10.0 menuconfig->Device Drivers->Network
>   Device Support->Universal TUN/TAP device driver support

Then save it as tun.config.

4

> make modules, it generate tun.ko under /drivers/net/ without err, then
>   copy it to lib/modules/4.10.0-42-generic/kernel/net/tun.ko.

And it still doesn't work. The command "modinfo tun" doesn't output anything.

Any advice about the install tun on Ubuntu 16.04?

Comment: Update:$modinfo tun
modinfo: ERROR: Module tun not found.

Answer (score 2):

You're probably on a VPS so you'll need to change this on your host settings.

- Login to your VPS control panel using your username and password.
- Click the ‘Manage’ button to the right of the VPS in which you want
  to enable tun/tap
- Under Controls -> Settings tab, click on ‘Enable TUN/TAP’
- A dialog box appears asking for confirmation, hit yes

Source: https://www.copahost.com/blog/openvpn-in-ubuntu-tun-tap/

I had this problem myself and just fixed it by doing exactly this.

Comment: Thanks. It's not related to VPS. I just only want to install TUN/TAP on my host.